nrf24 does not show all characters in the receiver
I am using Arduin mega (with RTC and DH22) and I wanna receive this values in receiver (UNO R4). The main problem is that in the receiver serial monitor does show all characters. When I increase the size of the payload or text in both, does not make change. Here are my code: The only way to include humidity and the rest of the characters is to delete some of the previous characters for example deleting Data or time or some of the empty characters in between.
[#include](tg://search_hashtag?hashtag=include) <SPI.h>
[#include](tg://search_hashtag?hashtag=include) <nRF24L01.h>
[#include](tg://search_hashtag?hashtag=include) <RF24.h>
[#include](tg://search_hashtag?hashtag=include) <DHT.h>
[#include](tg://search_hashtag?hashtag=include) <RtcDS1302.h>

RF24 radio(33, 32); // CE, CSN

const byte address[6] = "00001";

[#define](tg://search_hashtag?hashtag=define) DHTPIN 35     // Digital pin connected to the DHT sensor 
[#define](tg://search_hashtag?hashtag=define) DHTTYPE    DHT22     // DHT 22 (AM2302)

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

ThreeWire myWire(39, 41, 37); // IO, SCLK, CE
RtcDS1302<ThreeWire> Rtc(myWire);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  radio.begin();
  radio.openWritingPipe(address);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);
  radio.stopListening();

  dht.begin();

  Rtc.Begin();

  Serial.print("compiled: ");
  Serial.print(DATE);
  Serial.println(TIME);

  RtcDateTime compiled = RtcDateTime(DATE, TIME);
  printDateTime(compiled);
  Serial.println();

  if (!Rtc.IsDateTimeValid()) {
    Serial.println("RTC lost confidence in the DateTime!");
    Rtc.SetDateTime(compiled);
  }

  if (Rtc.GetIsWriteProtected()) {
    Serial.println("RTC was write protected, enabling writing now");
    Rtc.SetIsWriteProtected(false);
  }

  if (!Rtc.GetIsRunning()) {
    Serial.println("RTC was not actively running, starting now");
    Rtc.SetIsRunning(true);
  }

  RtcDateTime now = Rtc.GetDateTime();
  if (now < compiled) {
    Serial.println("RTC is older than compile time!  (Updating DateTime)");
    Rtc.SetDateTime(compiled);
  } else if (now > compiled) {
    Serial.println("RTC is newer than compile time. (this is expected)");
  } else if (now == compiled) {
    Serial.println("RTC is the same as compile time! (not expected but all is fine)");
  }
}

void loop() {
  float temperature = dht.readTemperature();
  float humidity = dht.readHumidity();

  RtcDateTime now = Rtc.GetDateTime();

  // Convert temperature, humidity, date, and time to strings
  char temperatureStr[6];
  dtostrf(temperature, 4, 2, temperatureStr); // Format: "%.2f"

  char humidityStr[6];
  dtostrf(humidity, 4, 2, humidityStr); // Format: "%.2f"

  char dateString[12];
  sprintf(dateString, "%04u/%02u/%02u", now.Year(), now.Month(), [now.Day](https://now.day/)());

  char timeString[9];
  sprintf(timeString, "%02u:%02u:%02u", now.Hour(), now.Minute(), now.Second());

  // Print date, time, temperature, and humidity in one line
  Serial.print(dateString);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(timeString);
  Serial.print(" T:");
  Serial.print(temperatureStr);
  Serial.print("°C H:");
  Serial.print(humidityStr);
  Serial.println("%");

  // Construct message payload
  char payload[500];
  sprintf(payload, "%s %s T:%s°C H:%s%%", dateString, timeString, temperatureStr, humidityStr);

  // Send payload via NRF24L01
  radio.write(&payload, sizeof(payload));


  delay(1000); // Adjust delay as needed
}

void printDateTime(const RtcDateTime& dt) {
  char datestring[50];
  snprintf_P(datestring, 
            sizeof(datestring),
            PSTR("%04u/%02u/%02u %02u:%02u:%02u"),
            dt.Year(),
            dt.Month(),
            [dt.Day](https://dt.day/)(),
            dt.Hour(),
            dt.Minute(),
            dt.Second() );
  Serial.print(datestring);
}

My Reciever:
[#include](tg://search_hashtag?hashtag=include) <SPI.h>
[#include](tg://search_hashtag?hashtag=include) <nRF24L01.h>
[#include](tg://search_hashtag?hashtag=include) <RF24.h>

RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN

const byte address[6] = "00001";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  radio.begin();
  radio.openReadingPipe(0, address);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);
  radio.startListening();
}

void loop() {
  if (radio.available()) {
    char text[500] = ""; // Increase the buffer size to ensure it can hold the entire payload
    [radio.read](https://radio.read/)(&text, sizeof(text));

    
    // Print the received payload
    Serial.println(text);

  }
}

Serial monitor:
sender:
2024/05/07 15:02:07 T:25.90°C H:48.90%

receiver:
2024/05/07 15:02:12 T:25.90°C H


It has fixed maximum packet size and for its payload it's around 32B
